# Can not close html5 application (wrapped on Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an application built in html5 and wrapped in phoneGap, by pressing the exit button the following function occurs:

```
function close_window() {
    if (confirm("Exit?")) {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}
```

It does not work..

On clicking the button the function close_window() occurs, 'but navigator.app.exitApp();' line not works.

I think it's because there is no child named app for navigator.. (I tested it in console)

Are there other ways to close an application?

Comment: which phonegap version do you use ?

Comment: had the same problem even with the newest version available... at the end, I've abandoned the idea, as Android/iPhone users do not close their apps and the behaviour is considered a non-standard and thus not very recommended for app devs

Comment: There are many applications with exit button .. Even if users on Android \ iPhone does not close the application, there is a possibility ...

Comment: phonegap --> newest version

Comment: Which newest version? if it's the one from github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android (which most code links still point to and is the top result in google), it is no longer the latest version and contains a bug in the app plugin. The actual latest code is at http://github.com/apache/cordova-android

Comment: What do you see in "adb logcat" when you click your exit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved ..

Exit application works by the function write-up question.

I have no idea what I changed that it works, **but it works!!**

Thanks for the help ..

:]

Comment: I know why now it works, I added to the JS of the HTML5, the JS of cordova (the PhoneGap) and then it worked.

Comment: The answer by Idan Gozlan is the correct answer; not this one. This answer is not even legible.

Answer (score 3):

Please be aware that exitApp function works only on android devices.
Which version of phonegap do you use?

Answer (score 0):

you could use BackButton.exitApp();